# Pass dynamic ID to url on success backbone

Tags: javascript, url, express, backbone.js

I get my id on click, i use destroy for delete it on my database, my id console.log work and return the value but i want to pass this id on the url like that:

```
'delete': 'http://localhost:3000/api/comments/'+ id
```

Error : Id is undefined and i can't pass it outdoor of my success.

Here  is my code :

```
    var PostPrimary = Backbone.Model.extend({
        methodToURL: {
            'read': 'http://localhost:3000/api/comments',
            'create': 'http://localhost:3000/api/comments',
            'update': 'http://localhost:3000/api/comments/:comment_id',
            'delete': 'http://localhost:3000/api/comments/:comment_id'
        },

        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            options = options || {};
            options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

            return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        idAttribute: "_id",
        defaults: {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        },
        postdata: function() {
            this.save({
                name: this.get('title'),
                content: this.get('content')
            }, {
                success: function(model) {
                    console.log("save");
                }
            });
        },
        deletedata: function() {
            this.destroy({
                success: function(model) {
                    //GET ID
                    id = model.get('idAttribute');
                    console.log(id);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return PostPrimary;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone model comes with the implementation of handling url's,You don't need methodtoURl property in your model.

specify `urlRoot` for your model and the id will be appended by backbone like `[urlRoot]/id`

your model can be simplified as

```
var PostPrimary = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: "_id",
        urlRoot: 'api/comments',
        defaults: {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        }
    });
```

The properties like Postdata are not needed you can directly say

```
Model.save() instead postdata, and model.destroy() instead deletedata()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have the id within your model you can create a closure.

```
  deletedata: function() {

    var id=this.get('idAttribute');

            this.destroy({
                success: function(model) {
                    //GET ID                   
                    console.log(id);
                }
            });
        }
```